# How to SUM the Duration_Hours when it is LEFT JOIN of another database table?

Tags: sql-server

I want to generate a report that summarizes the total working hours for every employee.

Below is my SQL query

```
SELECT WO_MaidName
      ,Maid_Name AS WO_selectMaidName
      ,Appointment_Duration
      ,Duration_Hours AS Appointment_selectDuration
FROM Appointments A
    LEFT JOIN Maid
        ON Maid_ID = WO_MaidName
    LEFT JOIN Duration
        ON Duration_ID = Appointment_Duration 
WHERE DATEPART(m, Appointment_DateTime) = DATEPART(m, DATEADD(m, -1, getdate()))
    AND DATEPART(yyyy, Appointment_DateTime) = DATEPART(yyyy, DATEADD(m, -1, getdate())) 
    AND (A.IsDelete = 0
        OR A.IsDelete IS NULL
        )
ORDER BY Appointment_ID DESC
```

The output is as follow which only display the working hours without adding these two value

[image]

How to `SUM` the `Duration_Hours` when it is `LEFT JOIN` of another database table so that the report will list the total working hours for every employee?

---

Edited:
I tried this query but giving me this:

> 'Column 'Maid.Maid_Name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.'

```
SELECT WO_MaidName
      ,Maid_Name AS WO_selectMaidName
      ,Appointment_Duration
      ,SUM(Duration_Hours) AS Appointment_selectDuration
FROM Appointments A
    LEFT JOIN Maid
        ON Maid_ID = WO_MaidName
    LEFT JOIN Duration
        ON Duration_ID = Appointment_Duration 
WHERE DATEPART(m, Appointment_DateTime) = DATEPART(m, DATEADD(m, -1, getdate()))
    AND DATEPART(yyyy, Appointment_DateTime) = DATEPART(yyyy, DATEADD(m, -1, getdate())) 
    AND (A.IsDelete = 0
        OR A.IsDelete IS NULL
        )
GROUP BY WO_MaidName
ORDER BY Appointment_ID DESC
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Why do you believe `SUM` will act differently when you use a `LEFT JOIN` to when you use an `INNER JOIN`? What Attempts have you made when using `SUM`, why didn't they work or product the results you expected?

Comment: @Larnu, I have edit my question

Comment: The error is telling you the problem here; `Maid_Name` and `Appointment_Duration` are invalid in the `SELECT` list as they aren't in the `GROUP BY` are not contained inside an aggregate function. What about that error don't you understand, as it's one of the far more clearly ones from SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is telling you what to do:

> 'Column 'Maid.Maid_Name' is invalid in the select list **because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.**'

All columns in a `select` query that perform an aggregation neet to either be aggregated or in a `group by`. You need to add both `Maid.Maid_Name` and `Appointment_Duration` to your `group by`.

Comment: I added this, GROUP BY Maid.Maid_Name, Appointment_Duration, but showing Column 'Appointments.WO_MaidName' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @user11381786  You are getting the same error as before... Can you not apply my answer to your situation?  What do you think that error means, given the version you were getting before and the version you are getting now that you have made a change?